# Fix the scale of Y-axis and X-axis in profile tool plugin in QGIS

Tags: qgis-plugins, graph, profile

As I change the size of the profile-tool window in QGIS, I get graphs of different sizes when I export them. Hence, it is not giving me repeatability since it is not convenient to compare graphs with different scales. I have attached the graphs and the different size of the profile-tool window

How do I fix the scale of Y-axis and X-axis of the graph so as to, irrespective to the window size of the tool, get the graph with the same scale?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to make this standardised is to export the profile data from the Table tab into something like Excel and then create standardised charts from there.